# How can I replace around a wildcard in a regex search?

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I'm trying to comment out all of the variable type declarations in a script I have, but I've run into this problem a few other times. I'd like to match a string, followed by a variable name, followed by a string and replace the exact text but with a single quote in front of the second string.

For example:

```
Dim variableName As Boolean
Dim variableName2 As String
```

should become:

```
Dim variableName 'As Boolean
Dim variableName2 'As String
```

Now, a problem is the I also have "As" strings elsewhere in the code that shouldn't be replaced, so a simple find/replace wont work.

I'm using NotePad++ and have the following regex that matches my declarations correctly:

```
Dim.*As
```

But I can't figure out what to put in place of the `.*` in the replace field. `Dim.*'As` obviously replaces the wildcard string with a literal `.*`, which is no good.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use RegEx "capture groups" to specify sections you want to capture and keep, and replace the rest.

In Notepad++ capture groups are represented by brackets (`(` and `)`), and you can put their content into the "Replace" by using notation such as `\1`, `\2`, etc. for each capture group you added (in order of appearance).

So, change your search RegEx to `(Dim.*)(As)`, which will find things as it did for you originally, but makes two capture groups.  One before where you want to insert the `'`, and one after.

To this will find `Dim variableName As Boolean` as before, and the two capture groups would contain `Dim variableName` and `As Boolean`.

For the Replace field in Notepad++, use `\1'\2`; this will replace the matched text with the first capture group, then the `'`, followed by the second capture group.

Perform your replace, and `Dim variableName As Boolean` becomes `Dim variableName 'As Boolean` (etc).

Comment: Submitted an edit request, but I believe the search string should be '(Dim.*?)(As)'. Adding the ? causes the search to take as little as possible, rather than matching the first Dim with the last As -- actually, this is only an issue in singleline searches, my bad

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a lookbehind and lookahead. 
For example:
Find:

```
(?<=Dim)(.*?)(?=As)
```

Replace With:

```
\1'
```

This should do what you are attempting to do. The '\1' in the replace matches the text between 'Dim' and 'As', allowing you to add a comment.

**Edit**

As a side note after I tested, this only works with Replace All

Comment: Strange, I wonder why it only works with Replace All. Anyone know?